# CSS: How to shift an element to right if it's sibiling is hidden?

Tags: css

I have three links... link-a  link-b link-c.

Under certain cirtcunmstances link-c is hidden, how can I make the link-b to shift right if link-c is not  present, and to the middle link-c is present? (these 3 links are inside a `display:flex div`)

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add a [mre]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: space-between;` for that purpose . If you specify `div` `width` than link will span upto the width else whole width be in consideration.

> Try to remove `.hidden` class to see effect of `justify-content: space-between;`

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="hidden">Link 3</a>
</div>
```